# Why Django Channels test suites and consumers are using different databases?

Tags: django, database, unit-testing, django-channels

Today, I ran into a problem with Django channels. I noticed that my test suites and and my consumers are using different databases.

For example if I create a fake User object (for authentication) in my test suites, My consumer doesn't have access to that fake user.

When I inspected the value of `User.objects.all()` inside my **test suite**, I got my fake user in the queryset but when I evaluated the same expersion inside my consumer's `connect` method, I got my **real users** in the original database which clearly shows that my consumer is not using the test database but it is using the **original database**.

I wanted to know why my consumer is using the **original database** instead of the **test database** which is supposed to contain fake data for testing purposes?

Here are all the packages I have installed:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgiref==3.4.1
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
autobahn==21.3.1
Automat==20.2.0
autopep8==1.5.7
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.3.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==3.4.7
daphne==3.0.2
Django==3.2
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-crum==0.7.9
django-extensions==3.1.3
django-filter==2.4.0
django-random-queryset==0.1.3
django-schema-graph==1.2.0
django-spaghetti-and-meatballs==0.4.2
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-recursive==0.1.2
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.6.0
drf-spectacular==0.15.1
factory-boy==3.2.0
Faker==8.10.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
hiredis==2.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.2
incremental==21.3.0
inflection==0.5.1
jsondiff==1.3.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
Markdown==3.3.4
msgpack==1.0.2
Pillow==8.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.1.0
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyrsistent==0.18.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.15.0
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.26.0
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
text-unidecode==1.3
toml==0.10.2
Twisted==21.7.0
twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.1
txaio==21.2.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.6
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

This is my consumer:

```
class PersonalChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer, AuthenticationMixin):

    def connect(self):
        super().connect()
        user = self.scope['user']
        contact_id = int(self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['user_id'])
        breakpoint()
        contact = self.get_contact_user(contact_id)
        if contact is None:
            self.close(); return

        chat_room = self.get_chat_room(user, contact)
        if chat_room is None:
            self.close(); return

        self.update_chat_room_channel_name(chat_room)
        self.scope['chat_room'] = chat_room

        sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            chat_room.get_group_name(), self.channel_name)

        new_msgs_count = chat_room.messages.filter(~Q(received_by=self.scope['user']))
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'command': 'msg_count',
            'msg_count': new_msgs_count
        }))
        recent_messages = chat_room.messages.all()[:30]
        self.send_message_bulk(recent_messages)
```

if you evaluate `User.objects.all()` in the `connect` method you will get the real users from the original database.

And here is my test suite:

```
@sync_to_async
def generate_messages(self):
    messages = [
        PersonalMessageFactory(
            sender=self.user_2, chat_room=self.chat_room,
            text='test'
        )
        for _ in range(0, 50)
    ]
    return messages

class TestPersonalChatConsumer(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.chat_room = PersonalChatRoomFactory()
        self.user_1 = self.chat_room.user_1
        self.user_2 = self.chat_room.user_2
        return super().setUp()

    async def test_we_can_get_messsages(self):
        messages = await generate_messages(self)
        breakpoint()
        com = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f'/chat/personal/{self.user_1.pk}/')
        connected, _ = await com.connect()
        self.assertTrue(connected)

        result = await com.receive_from()
        data = json.loads(result)
        self.assertEqual(data['command'], 'msg_count')
        self.assertEqual(data['msg_count'], 50)

        for _ in range (30):
            result = await com.receive_from()
            data = json.loads(result)
            self.assertEqual(data['command'], 'old_message')
            self.assertEqual(data['message']['text'], 'test')
        self.assertTrue(await com.receive_nothing())

        await com.disconnect()
```

if you evaluate `User.objects.all` (wrapped in sync_to_async) in the test method, you will get the fake users from the test database.

What should I do now? I want my consumers to be using the same database as my test suites. The documentation doesn't include much information about troubleshooting this sorts of problems.

If you have encountered this sort of problems before, please share your experience and help me solve my problem. Thank you all in advance.

If you need more information, please leave a comment down below. I'll provide all the necessary data.

Comment: That's a standard behavior. Test runner creates new database for each run and that is correct. You don't want your unit tests to use real database.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin I know that but the problem is my consumers are using the original database instead of the test database.

Comment: Where? In tests?

Comment: Yes. It seems that my test file are using the test database but my consumers are using original database (two databases totaly)

Comment: That's a quite odd. What test runner do you use? Where from ```TestCase``` is imported from?

Comment: I'm running tests with `python manage.py test` and TestCase is the standard django TestCase class imported from `django.test` module